# Oracle V$Session.SQL_ID is not populating

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

My organization recently upgraded form Oracle 10g to 11g. I had the following query that was working, but it no longer works because the V_$SESSION.SQL_ID field is not populated to link to.

```
SELECT SESS.OSUSER
     ,SESS.MACHINE
INTO v_USERID
    ,v_USERNAME
FROM SYS.V_$SQLAREA SEQL
JOIN SYS.V_$SESSION SESS ON SEQL.SQL_ID = SESS.SQL_ID
WHERE SEQL.SQL_TEXT LIKE 'DELETE%'
AND SEQL.SQL_TEXT LIKE '%ACCTLOG%';
```

Is there a work around I could use to obtain the same information?

Thanks all

Comment: V$session.sql_id is the id of the currently executing sql statement.  The session may not be executing a statement at the time you run your query.

Comment: As @OldProgrammer, mentioned in his comment, your query will not return any rows if there are no statements executing in the session. To Debug, try finding if your V_$SQLAREA contain any rows with the filter conditions specified.